# CakePHP MySQL Views

Tags: mysql, cakephp, view, cakephp-2.1

We are trying to profile accounts to build data that we want to compare against other accounts. For this we are using Mysql Views. I was wondering how to use the same using CakePHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view in MySQL is much like a table. So you can get the data in a view by calling it with a query:

```
$this->AnyModelName->query("SELECT * FROM my_view_1 WHERE 1");
```

You can also try to write a model that initially has `$this->useTable` set to false. Then if you define your own constructor for this class you may be able to initialize it with a different view every time. Check the Model documentation: [API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model) & [Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html).